# Why is my animation ignored when invoking a closure on the main thread?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, grand-central-dispatch

To remove a subView from the main view (the subView "dims" the parent view, hence why it's called dimView) I use an animation; it basically moves the subView toward the bottom of the screen and eventually out of the screen:

```
let centerY = CGRectGetMidY(view.bounds)
    let animation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    animation.removedOnCompletion = false
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    animation.fromValue = NSValue(CGPoint: view.center)
    animation.toValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPoint(x: view.center.x, y: 4 * centerY))
    animation.duration = 0.2
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn)
    dimView.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "DimRemovingAnimation")
```

Then through an event driven function I call this animation like so:

```
 @IBAction func done(sender: AnyObject) {

    let dimView = view.viewWithTag(1)
    if let dimView = dimView {

        removingAnimation(dimView)
        Delay.delay(0.4){

            dimView.removeFromSuperview()
        }

    }
}
```

This is my Delay class:

```
class Delay{



class func delay(delay: Double, block: () -> ()){


    let when = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(Int(delay) * Int(NSEC_PER_SEC)))

    dispatch_after(when, dispatch_get_main_queue(), block)
}

}
```

When I run this closure on the main thread (which is a serial thread, and should execute tasks in a serial manner) my animation is ignored and dimView is removed from the view hierarchy at once. However, when I run the closure on a global concurrent thread the animation is not ignored and the code successfully removes dimView of the hierarchy. But this is illegal since you must access UIKit from the main thread.

Can you please explain to me what the problem is when invoking the closure on the main thread? and a possible solution to my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're converting `delay` of `0.4` to an `Int`, which is `0`. I'd suggest replacing the reference to

```
Int64(Int(delay) * Int(NSEC_PER_SEC))
```

with

```
Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
```

---

As a further refinement, though, rather than triggering the removal after a certain amount of time has passed, I'd let the animation tell *you* when it's done. Easiest, you can use the block base `UIView` animation:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseIn, animations: { 
    dimView.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.center.x, y: 4 * centerY)
}, completion: { finished in
    dimView.removeFromSuperview()
})
```

Or, if you must use `CABasicAnimation`, specify its `delegate` and then implement `animationDidStop` delegate method to remove the view:

```
override func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
    dimView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

---

By the way, all of the above assumes you have not specified auto layout constraints for the `dimView`. If you have, rather than animating by changing the `frame`-related properties, you should modify those constraints and then animate the call to `layoutIfNeeded()`.